# How do I successfully deploy a react app to Azure

Tags: .net, reactjs, azure, npm

I am building a React .NET Core app. The build is fine locally, but in Azure, the React/npm part of the build fails. Below:

```
> melanies_site@0.1.0 build D:\home\site\repository\ClientApp
remote:   > react-scripts build
remote:   
remote:   'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
remote:   operable program or batch file.
remote:   
remote:   npm ERR! melanies_site@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote:   npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:   npm ERR! 
remote:   npm ERR! Failed at the melanies_site@0.1.0 build script.
remote:   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the melanies_site package,
remote:   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:   npm ERR!     react-scripts build
remote:   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
remote:   npm ERR!     npm owner ls melanies_site
remote:   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:   npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
remote:   npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
remote:   npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\repository\ClientApp
remote:   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
remote:   npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
remote:   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "melanies_site",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "engines": {
        "node": "10.15"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
        "react": "^16.0.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
        "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
        "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
}
```

I'm new to react development and new to using Azure. I created this app using `dotnet new react -o my-new-app`

I've tried installing react-scripts via npm.
Also tried adding

```
"engines": {
        "node": "10.15"
    },
```

to the package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do to resolve something like this:

- Update all my dependencies with the latest version( keeping * instead of version in package.json)
- Delete your **`package-lock.json`**
- Try running npm install from administrator model
- try running npm audit fix
- Delete the Npm and npm-cache folder

Additional reference: Please take a look at below thread:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1627

See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy my app to Azure.

When I posted this question, I was attempting to use Kudu for deployment (continuous integration). I still have not found the solution to deploying this way.

Now, I run the following terminal/console command in the root directory:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish
```

Then I use my FTP client to deploy the files from /publish.